# Target nested router view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to figure out how to structure this but currently struggling,

Think of it  like facebook, where if you are  logged in  facebook.com goes to your personal feed, but if you are not logged in you go to the homepage/login (both same url)

- If the user is not logged in i want `/` to go to home component
- If user is logged in I want `/` to go to the dashboard component

Then `/settings`, `/profile` etc should fill out the `router-view` inside dashboard component

`/login`, `/signup` should use up the `router-view` in the App.vue

Currently my router-views are nested. so e.g `/settings` just ends up in the first outer one.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37691192/3226121) can help

Comment: I think this one will solve your task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275453/523630