# I would like to use the same route from two components how can I do this using vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to use the same route to display different components based on whether or not the client is authenticated. I am unable to find info on this in the router documentation. Here is the same question but the answer seems to be outdated as router.map is deprecated.
[Vue.js - two different components on same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673929/vue-js-two-different-components-on-same-route) 
Please point me in the right direction,
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if dynamic routing within the router itself is supported at this time. An alternative is to load a wrapper component in your router. Then that component determines what nested components to show.

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: WrapperComponent
    }
]
```

```html
<!-- WrapperComponent -->
<template v-if="auth">
    <auth-view />
</template>
<template v-else>
    <non-auth-view />
<template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mulitple components on a single path using [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) :

example :

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        component1,
        component2
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<!-- this will display component1 on the path '/' -->
<router-view name="component1"></router-view>

<!-- this will display component2 on the path '/' -->
<router-view name="component2"></router-view>
```